# Get my current profile photo in moodle

Tags: php, laravel, moodle

Im trying to get the current profile photo in moodle, i found that you can get it by using an url `moodle/user/pix.php/."id"./f1.jpg` and it works half way.

When i change the picture or delete it, using the same url gets the first img and not the new one.

The previous url redirects to an url like this `moodle/pluginfile.php/5/user/icon/f1`, in this example adds the 5 in de url.

Im not workin inside de moodle project, im in a project that contains moodle and i need to get the picture

Answer (score 0):

moodle/user/pix.php/."id"./f1.jpg used to work in previous versions of Moodle. However, in newer versions  (Moodle 2.3.2+), they use http://my.site.com/pluginfile.php/'$id'/user/icon/f1

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

to get current profile picture, you can try this on 3.4 version

```
<?php echo new moodle_url('/user/pix.php/'.$USER->id.'/f1.jpg')?>
```

Hope this help you, thanks